# use dynamic valuse based on the datafactory pipeline name

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am using the email.json config file from the storage account where I have data as below:

```
{
    "DvD145": "alfred.m@app.com,moris.l@app.com",
    "TeD149": "victor@app.com",
    "PdD148": "lowed@app.com"
}
```

I am using the following code in the data factory

```
{
    "name": "pipeline2",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Lookup1",
                "type": "Lookup",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "JsonSource",
                        "storeSettings": {
                            "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                            "recursive": false,
                            "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                        },
                        "formatSettings": {
                            "type": "JsonReadSettings"
                        }
                    },
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "Json1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "firstRowOnly": false
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Set variable1",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Lookup1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "ToEmail",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "@activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].DvD145",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "variables": {
            "ToEmail": {
                "type": "String"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGPrp.png)

the above code is working fine when I provide the pipeline name in the dynamic content as

```
@activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].DvD145
```

I was trying to make it dynamic which would be specific to each environment pipeline

```
@activity('Lookup1').output.value[pipeline().DataFactory]
```

but this approach is throwing an error saying

```
The expression 'activity('Lookup1').output.value[pipeline().DataFactory]' cannot be evaluated because property 'DvD145' cannot be selected. Array elements can only be selected using an integer index.
```

can I get some suggestions on how to rectify the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The expression activity('Lookup1').output.value[pipeline().DataFactory]' cannot be evaluated because property 'DvD145' cannot be selected. Array elements can only be selected using an integer index.

The above error happens because of `activity('Lookup1').output.value` is an array value and the index of this should be integer but `pipeline().DataFactory` is a string value

The below is my json with columns names as datafactory workspace name

```
{
"azV123":"alfred.m@app.com,moris.l@app.com",
"TeD149":"victor@app.com",
"PdD148":"lowed@app.com"
}
```

you can get the datafactory  name dynamicly with this below expresion :

```
@activity('Lookup1').output.value[0][pipeline().DataFactory]
```

[image: Ref1]

**Output:**

[image: Ref2]